# Отфильтровать объект по условию и записать результат в новый объект

Tags: javascript, obj

Нужно отфильтровать объект по условию что его значения больше или равно 18:

```
console.log(getAdults({ 'John Doe': 19, Tom: 17, Bob: 18}));
        
// Output: { 'John Doe': 19, Bob: 18 }
        
console.log(getAdults({ Franky: 7, Ann: 40 })); 
    
// Output: { Ann: 40 }
```

Только начал учить объекты, но именно такой информации не нашел в интернете. Хочу разобраться как это работает пока что с помощью цикла for..in

```
const getAdults = obj => {

    let filteredObj = {};

    for (let key in obj) {
        if (obj[key] >= 18) {
            filteredObj = obj;
        }
        return filteredObj;
    }
};
```

Помогите пожста исправить код чтобы условие выполнилось.

Comment: Давайте поставлю вопрос по другому, должно помочь вам) Из объекта `A` вставить в новый объект `B` только те ключи-значения, значения, которых удовлетворяют некому условию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return сразу прерывает цикл и выходит из него. return  надо ставить в конце метода. А вообще можно пойти по обратному пути: если значение меньше 18, то удалить ключ из объекта. Если хочется, чтобы объект не изменялся, то в начале метода, можно работать с копией

```js
const getAdults = obj => {    
    for (let key in obj) {        
        if (obj[key] < 18) {
            delete(obj[key]);            
        }        
    }

    return obj;
};

console.log(getAdults({ 'John Doe': 19, Tom: 17, Bob: 18}));
```

В целом можно сделать так:

```js
const getAdults = obj => {    
    let filteredObj = {};
    
    for (let key in obj) {        
        if (obj[key] >= 18) {
            filteredObj[key] = obj[key];            
        }        
    }

    return filteredObj;
};

console.log(getAdults({ 'John Doe': 19, Tom: 17, Bob: 18}));
```

Comment: Не учи плохому))) Да и зачем работать с копией, когда можно просто сразу вставить в пустой объект то что надо?)

Comment: понял в чем была моя ошибка. Да, мне надо чтобы текущий объект не изменялся. Я return поставил выше чем надо. И вместо filteredObj = obj; нужно было filteredObj[key] = obj[key];

Comment: @EzioMercer оке

Comment: @Ector добавил второй ответ как раз за секунду до коммента)

Comment: да-да, оно)) уже так и подправил у себя в vscode)